# Black Screen Error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

So recently i set up an intent where when a button is clicked it brings up a new activity. It works fine but when I go to the activity and then try to go back to the main screen I get a black screen. At the black screen if I hit back one more time it takes me to the main menu but this is annoying. Any ideas?

**playbutton.java**

```
package com.Dragon_Fruit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class playbutton extends Activity {

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(playbutton.this, PlayActivity.class);
        playbutton.this.startActivity(myIntent);

    }

}
```

**PlayActivity.java**

```
package com.Dragon_Fruit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class PlayActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playscreen);

}
}
```

**PlayActivity in the Manifest**

```
<activity android:name=".PlayActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**DragonFruitActivity.java**

```
package com.Dragon_Fruit;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class DragonFruitActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // ***BUTTON SOUND***//
        final MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(
                DragonFruitActivity.this, R.raw.button_click);

        ImageButton playbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
        playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                arg0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbuttonselected);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(buttonSound.isPlaying()) {
                    buttonSound.stop();
                }

                try {
                    buttonSound.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                buttonSound.start();

                startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this,
                        playbutton.class));
            }

        });
        ImageButton settingsbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.settingsbutton);
        settingsbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(buttonSound.isPlaying()) {
                    buttonSound.stop();
                }

                try {
                    buttonSound.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                buttonSound.start();

                startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this,
                        settingsbutton.class));
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first activity never sets a layout.  In the code shown, it looks like you're going from `playbutton` to `PlayActivity`.  When you press back in `PlayActivity`, it goes back to `playbutton`.  Since you never called `setContentView()` on any layout in `playbutton`, it's just a black screen that does nothing.  It seems like you should just remove the `playbutton` activity.

Comment: sorry I might have worded that wrong. When my application starts up it launches DragonFruitActivity.java which sets the layout to an xml I made. I then used two image buttons to be the main buttons on the screen. When the play button (playbutton activity) was pushed i wanted it to start a new activity. Is this the right way to go about things? I will put the DragonFruitActivity.java in my question.

Comment: Hey I figured it out thanks for your help you were right the playbutton activity was taking to many steps.

Comment: Replace `startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this, playbutton.class));` with `startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this, PlayActivity.class));`  There's no reason to start a new activity to start a new activity.

Comment: Ya hahaha I noticed that. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the playbutton Activity from your main thread and then just calling PlayActivity in the onCreate(), you are adding an unnecessary step.

Just move

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(playbutton.this, PlayActivity.class);
    playbutton.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

From your playbutton Activity to your main Activity